# CodeIgniter list not respecting permissions and displaying too much information

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I make this code to list only the sales of the respective vendors? Currently it is displaying all orders.

It is not properly listing the data coming from the database, does not filter properly.

Controller:

```
function index(){
$this->gerenciar();}

function gerenciar(){

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/os/gerenciar/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->os_model->count('os');
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['next_link'] = 'Próxima';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Anterior';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination alternate"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a style="color: #2D335B"><b>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_link'] = 'Primeira';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Última';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     

    $this->data['results'] = $this->os_model->get('os','idOs,dataInicial,garantia,descricaoProduto,defeito,usuarios_id,status,observacoes,desconto,trocas','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->data['view'] = 'os/os';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo',$this->data);
}
```

MODEL:

```
    function get($table,$fields,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){

    $this->db->select($fields.',clientes.nomeCliente, clientes.tabelaPreco');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->join('clientes','clientes.idClientes = os.clientes_id');
    $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    $this->db->order_by('idOs','desc');
    if($where){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
    return $result;
}
```

VIEW:

```
<?php           
    foreach ($results as $r) {
        if ($this->session->userdata('id') == $r->usuarios_id || $this->session->userdata('id') == '1') {
        $dataInicial = date(('d/m/Y'),strtotime($r->dataInicial));
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$r->idOs.' -'.$r->usuarios_id.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r->nomeCliente.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$dataInicial.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r->status.'</td>';

        echo '<td>';
        if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vOs')){
            echo '<a style="margin-right: 1%" href="'.base_url().'index.php/os/visualizar/'.$r->idOs.'" class="btn tip-top" title="Ver mais detalhes"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>'; 
        }
        if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'eOs')){
            echo '<a style="margin-right: 1%" href="'.base_url().'index.php/os/editar/'.$r->idOs.'" class="btn btn-info tip-top" title="Editar OS"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i></a>'; 
        }
        if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'dOs')){
        echo '<a href="#modal-excluir" role="button" data-toggle="modal" os="'.$r->idOs.'" class="btn btn-danger tip-top" title="Excluir OS"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>  '; 
        }
        echo  '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Provide more information!

Comment: how are you querying for results?? I think you've posted wrong code

Comment: I put more information. Help?

Comment: Still not enough infos, you need to give us the output you are getting and the output you want at least.

Answer (score 0):

You are not filtering the records in your model. your `$where` is empty so the sql will return all the records.

you should get the vendor id from session or parameter and then pass it to your model with a where condition.